# ASP.Net Core 3 использование двух контекстов с одной базой данных

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

При разработке приложения необходимо добавить регистрацию, планирую использовать Identity, но столкнулся с проблемой стоит ли разграничивать контекст для Identity, наследовав его от IdentityDbContext и контекст для данных приложения используя DbContext. Данные будут хранится в одной базе данных. Какой подход является лучшей практикой в данном случае?

Comment: Зачем разграничивать? В чем мотивация этого?

Comment: Как вы собираетесь управлять миграциями при разграничении?

Comment: Имхо если строгой не необходимости в одной базе нет, то я бы сделал именно раздельно для каждого контекста своя база. Два контекста на одну базу возможно, есть только но с миграцией. Но если разберетесь как её делать раздельно то и это не помеха.

Comment: @Vasek вопрос больше не в том, насколько сложно это сделать, а в том, какой в этом смысл. Если автор хочет все делать "правильно", то уровень доступа к данным все равно должен быть абстрагирован от реальных запросов, а что у абстракции под капотом - один контекст, два или вообще прямые запросы в БД - уже не так важно. Так зачем тратить на это время, если это, по сути, не принесет никаких бенефитов?

Answer (score 0):

Более правильным подходом будет создание двух отдельных контекстов и двух отдельных баз данных.

Но в целом это всё очень зависит конкретно от вашего случая, возможно при решении простой задачи нет смысла усложнять реализацию.